# What is the change in .trigger() in jquery1.9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-migrate, jquery-trigger

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

I got this below detail from the link. But what is it that is changing in trigger(click)
event? I wasnt clear with this below explanation.

link Checkbox/radio state in a .trigger()ed "click" event

When the user clicks on a checkbox or radio button, the event handler sees the node in the state it will be in if event.preventDefault() is not called on the node--in essence, its new state. So for example, if the user clicks on an unchecked checkbox, the event handler will see a checked box. Before 1.9, a synthetic event triggered by either .trigger("click") or .click() would see the checkbox in the opposite state than that of a user action. This has been fixed in 1.9 to reflect the same checked state as a user-initiated action.

Comment: `Before 1.9, a synthetic event triggered by either .trigger("click") or .click() would see the checkbox in the opposite state than that of a user action.` What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Do i need any fix in my code? i already have this being used.

Comment: It depends on your code. You might have to. Unless the state that the checkbox is in is not important (only the change of state is important).

Comment: im not manipulating this against a checkbox, just on a div. To summarize, only when .trigger(click) is used for a radio button/checkbox, I need to validate if the change of state is affected? Am i right>